# Rotate to the end of container

Tags: c++, stl

I want to make a rotation similar to `std::rotate` but in way that the `middle` iterator will become the new last element istead of the new first element

Comment: Great. Go ahead and do that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you just need the element that follows the `middle` iterator to become the new begin. Rotate with that as `middle`. Eg

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
void rotate_last(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator middle, ForwardIterator last)
{
    ForwardIterator itn(middle);
    if (middle != last)
    {
       std::advance(itn, 1);
    }
    if (itn != last)
    {
       std::rotate(first, itn, last);
    }
}
```